# Send email attachment using send grid

Tags: java, spring-boot, sendgrid

I am using `sendgrid:4.1.2` to send mails. I attached images into my mail. While I received the mail, the attached images are not opening, image viewer says- `Premature end-of-file encountered`. I am using the following code to attach files into mail object:

```
 /*Prepare the email to be sent*/
        Mail mail = new Mail();
        mail.addPersonalization(personalization);
        mail.setFrom(from);
        mail.setSubject(subject);

/*Prepare the attachments for the mail */
        if (attachments != null && attachments.size() > 0) {
            for (EmailAttachmentDo emailAttachmentDo : attachments) {
                Attachments attachment = new Attachments();
                attachment.setContent(new 
   String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(emailAttachmentDo.getContent())));
                attachment.setType("IMAGE");
                attachment.setFilename("image-name.png");
                attachment.setDisposition("attachment");
                attachment.setContentId(emailAttachmentDo.getContentId());
                mail.addAttachments(attachment);
            }
        }

/*Make a send email request*/
        Request request = new Request();
        request.setMethod(Method.POST);
        request.setEndpoint("mail/send");
        request.setBody(mail.build());

        Response response = sendGrid.api(request)
```

**Note :** After encoding  attached image content into Base64 string I got this:

`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`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to solve the issue is to encode the attachment using commons apache [codec commons-codec-1.8.ja](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi)r and its `encodeAsString` method from package

> org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

```
Attachments attachments3 = new Attachments();
Base64 x = new Base64();
String imageDataString = x.encodeAsString(fileData);
attachments3.setContent(imageDataString);
attachments3.setType("image/png");//"application/pdf"
attachments3.setFilename("x.png");
attachments3.setDisposition("attachment");
attachments3.setContentId("Banner");
mail.addAttachments(attachments3);
```

Even the content-length was retruned as 0 in response **it worked**.

Comment: @Arun I tried this and got the same result and I don't think that there is any issue with encoding.

Comment: @mohammadhashim As you have set Wrong setType I have also mentioned `setType("image/png");` try changing this. Because this is working very well from my end. as I have used this in earlier project.

Comment: Yes, I missed type, now I set type as `image/*` and it is working. Thank you.

Comment: @mohammadhashim Please keep it marked as Correct answer, so that it will be useful for others who face this type of issue, as well it is good to appreciate to one who has Answered and given his best affords to you.